# adding POST to the SimpleHTTPServer as proxy

Tags: python, http, post, vbulletin, simplehttpserver

**UPDATED**
I've made simple proxy based on `SimpleHTTPServer` but i've got problem with POST method when someone is requesting with POST method  it show Error so i've made `do_POST()` function,but when i requesting with POST (works fine with most site except `vbulletin script !`) i just get page says:The connection was reset

so now the problem is when i try to login at `vbulletin` site it said  The connection was reset 
i have no idea why !

```
class Proxy(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
      print self.address_string()
      print "User ip:",self.client_address[0]
      print self.date_time_string()#return time
      print self.path
      print self.headers
      self.copyfile(urllib.urlopen(self.path), self.wfile)
      print "--------------------------------------------\n"
    #this is the function where is the problem 
    def do_POST(self):
      print "=====================\n"
      print self.raw_requestline
      print self.headers.getheaders("Content-Length")
      length = int(self.headers.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
      post_data = urlparse.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(length))
      self.copyfile(urllib.urlopen(self.path,urllib.urlencode(post_data)),self.wfile)
      print "=====================\n"
```

hopefully i can get hint about it

Comment: I suspect your do_POST() is throwing an error. Comment out the whole function and un-comment line by line and you will probably find the issue.

Comment: actually i've discovered  it's works with most web sites , but when i tried to login in site that's installed vbulletin it said The connection was reset

Comment: @pd40 i believe self.copyfile() is the issue

Comment: So how did you fixed it ?